# Image Map in C# Windows Phone 8.1 application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am making a windows phone 8.1 application using C# and XAML and I want to implement an Image map.
I know how to do it in HTML using `img` tag's `usemap` attribute, but how using C# and XAML?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404014/is-there-any-way-of-doing-an-image-map-on-xaml

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"     
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Width="500" Height="500">
   <Canvas.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="yourBackgroundImage.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
  </Canvas.Background>

  <Rectangle Width="50" Height="25" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100" />
  <Rectangle Width="100" Height="20" Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="300" />
  <!-- etc -->
</Canvas>
```

The `Canvas` with a background image is analogous to your `<img>` and the set of `Rectangle` elements are similar to your `<area>` tags inside your `<map>`. You can add events to the `Rectangle` for things like `Tap`, you could give them a `Fill` property to make them a given color, etc.